Flutter Music Resume when app closed using audio service package
I'm facing a problem my music is playing successfully everything is working is but the problem is that i want to resume the the music from notifications MediaAction Buttons i've stored teh last queue in hive now i want to get access when that button is pressed so that i can load the recently played music and resume it.
Like After one to two hours.
I've tried multiple things but nothing works fine.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
